# Array of Pointer in C

Tags: arrays

I am a bit confused in Understanding the below array of pointer code

```
    int main()
    {
        int *p={10,118,225};
        printf("%d ",p);  // Output will be 10
        //printf("%d ",*p);      Segmentation Fault error
        p=20;
        printf("%d ",p);    // Overwrite the previous data
    }
```

Below are my questions

1. while learning pointer i understood that on de-referencing the pointer 
   printf("%d ",*p) it will give the data, but here i am getting segmentation 
   fault error.
2. why printf("%d ",p); is printing the data, it should suppose to print the 
   base address, and how i can obtained the output of the base address
3. in which memory the *p={10,118,225}; array stored. (stack or heap)
4. Is there any way to access all the element of *p={10,118,225}
5. for p=20; the data overwrite, is there any way to access previous data 
   without assigning previous data to other pointer.

If you guys can share me the link of the above tutorial, it will be more helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%d` to print out a pointer is wrong, you should use `%p` and cast the pointer to `void*`.

When you use the initializer list for the pointer it’s not creating an array. It’s setting the value for the pointer, which becomes 10. If you dereference a random memory address anything may happen. Usually a segmentation fault since you’re not allowed to touch the memory at that location.

If you want to create an array you’d use

```
int p[] = { 10, 2, 30 };
```

Assigning a value to a pointer doesn’t change the value pointed to by the pointer either.

Answer (score 0):

`int* p` is a pointer to integer variable and it will only accept data of the same type. You can declare a separate 1D array. and then u can assign the address of the first element of the array to that pointer `p` like this:

`int array [3] =  {10,118,225};
int *p = array;
printf("%d ",p);  // printing the address of the first element in the array
printf("%d ",*p); // printing the value stored at the address of the first element in the array which is 10;`

The statement `p=20;`is invalid because `p` is a pointer to `int` variable and it will only accepts data of the same type. You can't assign an `int` to a `pointer`